# Selecting rows from matrix using logical conditions

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have two matrices A and B. Matrix B is formed by selecting some rows of A such that number of rows in B <= number of rows in A. Now I have to make a matrix C such that it should contain only those rows from A which are not present in B. Eg as follows

```
A = 1 2
    2 3 
    3 4
    4 5
    5 6 

B = 2 3
    4 5 

C = 1 2
    3 4
    5 6
```

I have been given matrices A and B and their dimensions. I tried using 'where' as follows but I am getting segmentation error.

```
  where(A(:,:).ne.B(:,:))
     C(:,1) = A(:,1)
     C(:,2) = A(:,2)
  end where
```

Can anyone tell me how to write proper logical conditions for 'where' or any different method to achieve this. Thanks.

PS: There would be no repeating rows. The sequence of rows in B will match that of A.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark edited. Thanks for pointing it out. Can you please look at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *where-construct* is never going to work, the arrays are all different sizes and not conformable for assignments or logical operations.  Loops are the way to go.

Given your declarations for `A` and `B` I might declare `C` like this

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: c
```

and an index array (whose use will become apparent in a few more lines) such as

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(SIZE(a,1)) :: indx = [(ix,ix=1,SIZE(a,1))]
```

Next, allocate `C`

```
ALLOCATE(c(SIZE(a,1)-SIZE(b,1),SIZE(a,2)))
```

Next, loop over the elements of `B` and of `A`.  (Note that like Fortran I am case insensitive.  Note also that I've looped over the elements of `B` first, then over `A`.  If either `A` or `B` was much larger I might take more care to sort out the order of the loops and to `exit` the inner loop when a match is found.)  As the loops proceed set the corresponding index value to `0`.

```
  DO jx = 1, SIZE(b,1)
     DO ix = 1, SIZE(a,1)
        IF (ALL(a(ix,:)==b(jx,:))) indx(ix) = 0  
     END DO
  END DO
```

And, finally, we can populate `C` thusly:

```
c = a(PACK(indx,indx/=0),:)
```